# git hook scripts in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

How do I add git hook scripts for pre-commit checks to azure repos, any prerequisites?
Do we need to place the git hook script in the repo itself in a separate folder?

Comment: do you want the git hooks will be in the server side? if yes, it's impossible.

Comment: I want the git hooks for the pre commit checks for the developers before they commit their code to the azure repo

Comment: each developer need to add the hook in his local repo

Answer (score 0):

The pre-commit checks need to be placed to .git -> hook folder.

So you need to add the git hook scripts to your `each local repo -> .git folder -> hooks`.

[image]

.git folder contains local configurations and informations, so it's not on the remote server.

the .git folder will not be pushed to the azure repo.

So you need to add the git hook scripts to your each local repo on your local machine

Comment: I guess the OP wants to execute the scripts on the remote and not locally.